# Can PyQt4 and Qt4/C++ co-exist peacefully on Windows?

Tags: windows, qt4, pyqt

I had previously installed PyQt4 on my Windows XP machine and was successful in getting everything to run. This evening, I downloaded the full Qt4 SDK (open source version) and installed it as well. After adding the path to the bin directory to my system environment path I was able to build a few small programs I'd written in C++. Without changing my environment, I started up python and tried to import PyQt4.QtCore and got an error that it couldn't load the DLL. I removed from my environment path, the path to the Qt4 SDK bin directory and was now able to run my python PyQt4 programs but I could no longer build my C++ programs.

First off, I'm not sure why the presence of the C++ SDK should impact the python version because they're in different directories. I assume the issue is that, when python attempts to load the PyQt4 DLL, it thinks its using an executable from the python path but, because the SDK path is first, that (incompatible) version is what is actually invoked.

Is there a way that these two environments can leave peacefully with each other such that I can build and run either type of program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, as you correctly suggest, tends to be that the versions of the various DLLs (QtCore4.dll, QtGui4.dll etc) are different.  I've tended to find that the problem occurs for the one expecting a newer version (so if the Qt SDK is installed second, but PyQt4 is in the path first, the Qt SDK would complain), but it sounds like you've got a different problem.

There are two solutions that I've found to this:

- Change your path for the different build/run environments (not very nice).
- Make sure both PyQt4 and Qt/C++ are at the same Qt version so that either DLL will work (generally much easier).

Since I have started installing both PyQt4 and Qt/C++ on a computer when I first start using it (and therefore they are at equivalent release versions), I have rarely had any problems with them coexisting.

Comment: That was it. I ended up downloading Qt4 and and built PyQt4 using its libraries and tools. Now everybody is happy.